# WM_GETMINMAXINFO does not seem to work. How to get a window's minimum and maximum possible size?

Tags: mfc, window, size, max, minimum

I am using MFC. I have a custom dialog that has been created from the application's resource file (designed with the Visual Studio 6 dialog designer), and I need to get the min/max info from it. I do the following:

```
MINMAXINFO minMaxInfo;
LRESULT lresult = m_wnd->SendMessage(WM_GETMINMAXINFO, 0, (LPARAM)&minMaxInfo);
```

The value 'lresult' is 0, meaning that the message was processed by the application. However, the minMaxInfo structure is not filled with meaningful values.

Does the above code have a bug? is there another way to get the min/max info from a dialog?

I do not want to handle the MINMAXINFO message myself.

Answer (score 0):

According to the MSDN:

*"Sent to a window when the size or position of the window is about to change. An application can use this message to override the window's default maximized size and position, or its default minimum or maximum tracking size."*

Ergo, as it is not going through a re-size, the information isn't there.

EDIT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632626(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you check out [Microsoft's documentation for WM_GETMINMAXINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632626(VS.85).aspx) you'll see that Windows initializes the structure with default values before it sends the message. The default handler for the message will leave those values unchanged; I'm guessing you never initialized those values yourself, and that's why you're not seeing meaningful values.

It's possible that the message doesn't do what you think it does and wouldn't be useful anyway. When I have a resizeable dialog I put a `GetWindowRect` in my `OnInitDialog` and save that as the minimum size of the window. I've never felt a need to restrict the maximum size.